# I feel this exercise C.2-7 is strange. ("Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS) (Keywords: Probability, mutually independent)

Tags: probability, independence

I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS.

This book contains the following exercise(C.2-7).

> A collection $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n$ of events is said to be pairwise independent if
> $$\text{Pr}\{A_i\cap A_j\}=\text{Pr}\{A_i\}\text{ Pr}\{A_j\}$$
> for all $1\leq i<j\leq n$. We say that the events of the collection are (mutually)
> independent if every $k$-subset $A_{i_1}, A_{i_2}, \dots, A_{i_k}$ of the collection, where $2\leq k\leq n$ and $1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq n$, satisfies $$\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}\}=\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{i_2}\}\cdots\text{Pr}\{A_{i_k}\}.$$

> Exercise C.2-7
> Show how to construct a set of $n$ events that are pairwise independent but such that no subset of $k>2$ of them is mutually independent.

I feel this exercise is strange.
The reason why I feel this exercise is strange is here:

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ be $n$ events.
Let $k=3$.
Let $\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},A_{i_3}\}\subset\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ and $\#\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},A_{i_3}\}=3$.
Since the collection $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ must be pairwise independent and the $3$-subset $\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},A_{i_3}\}$ must not be mutually independent, $$\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3}\}\ne\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{i_2}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{i_3}\}$$ must hold.
So, for any $3$-subset $\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},A_{i_3}\}$ of $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$, $$\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3}\}\ne\text{Pr}\{A_{i_1}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{i_2}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{i_3}\}$$ must hold.
Let $k>3$.
Let $\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},\dots,A_{i_k}\}\subset\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ and $\#\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},\dots,A_{i_k}\}=k$.
Let $\{A_i,A_j,A_l\}\subset\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},\dots,A_{i_k}\}$.
Then, $$\text{Pr}\{A_{i}\cap A_{j}\cap A_{l}\}\ne\text{Pr}\{A_{i}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{j}\}\text{ Pr}\{A_{l}\}$$ holds.
So, by definition, $k$ subset $\{A_{i_1},A_{i_2},\dots,A_{i_k}\}$ is not mutually independent automatically.

So, I wonder why CLRS didn't write as follows:

> Exercise C.2-7
> Show how to construct a set of $n$ events that are pairwise independent but such that no subset of $k=3$ of them is mutually independent.

Is this exercise ok?

Comment: How does it contradict the exercise?

Comment: I just wonder why CLRS didn't write as follows:  
Show how to construct a set of $n$ events that are pairwise independent but such that no subset of $k=3$ of them is mutually independent.

Comment: The exercise could have been written that way $-$ as you show, it comes to the same thing. So there is no reason to prefer one formulation over the other, I would say. But the interesting part is constructing $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$.

Comment: @md5 Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you very much for your comment.